# Where to place breacrumb markup?

Tags: schema.org, breadcrumbs

Where should I put breadcrumb markup? On the target page or on the linking page?

For example, if I have the following structure:

`Home
-BallGames
--Baseball
--Football
-BoardGames
--NonGambling
---Chess
---Checkers`

Do I place the following code (for breadcrumbs) in, say, chess, checkers, and all the "destination" files or do I have to mark it up in the "linking" files (Home,BoardGames, and NonGambling)

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 1,
      "item": {
        "@id": "http://example.com",
        "name": "Home"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 2,
      "item": {
        "@id": "http://example.com/BoardGames",
        "name": "BallGames"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 3,
      "item": {
        "@id": "http://example.com/BoardGames/NoGambling",
        "name": "NonGambling"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 4,
      "item": {
        "@id": "http://example.com/BoardGames/NoGambling/chess"
        "name": "chess"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not sure you are getting what breadcrumbs are, so I want to clarify and hopefully not insult. Breadcrumbs are links in series that  link to pages in the hierarchy path above the page a user is on and not to pages not within the hierarchy. Using your example, the page football would have links to ballgames and home. Traditionally, the last element would not be a link at all, but the page the user is on. Your breadcrumb code should reflect this hierarchy. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to implement [*location*-based Breadcrumbs](https://audisto.com/insights/guides/2/#location-based-breadcrumb-navigation-5bbbc1cd03ab665b8d006a003a277236) (those that reflect the site's folder/page structure) then this particular code-block you've supplied would be on the `chess` page itself.

You wouldn't be able to reference the `chess` page in the breadcrumbs of the parent `NoGambling` page, since there are other alternative(s) (`checkers` in this case) - Note, the `NoGambling` page should also contain their relevant schema breadcrumb markup, along with all the other pages.

[It's recommended](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G65.html) to omit the hyperlink on the last item (the current page), testing using Google's [Structured Data tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) without the `@id` value in the last list item works fine.

P.S. there's a missing `,` in your example at the end of the 4th `@id`.